# Angular UI Bootstrap popover with close button

Tags: popover, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using Angular UI Bootstrap to create a popover but I am unable to find the option to add a close button inside the popover.

I customized the popover template to include the close button. But I am still unable to find a function/event to close the popover. Setting *isOpen* to false works for the first time as it just overwrites the function - but thereafter becomes unusable.

```
 <button popover-placement="bottom" popover="test">POPOVER WITH CLOSE<button>
```

Here is the template script:

```
angular.module("template/popover/popover.html", []).run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put("template/popover/popover.html",
    "<div class=\"popover {{placement}}\" ng-class=\"{ in: isOpen(), fade: animation() }\">\n" +
    "  <div class=\"arrow\"></div>\n" +
    "\n" +
    "  <div class=\"popover-inner\">\n" +
    "      <button ng-click=\"isOpen = !isOpen()\" class=\"btn-popover-close btn btn-primary\">Close</button>\n" +
    "      <h3 class=\"popover-title\" ng-bind=\"title\" ng-show=\"title\"></h3>\n" +
    "      <div class=\"popover-content\" ng-bind=\"content\"></div>\n" +
    "  </div>\n" +
    "</div>\n" +
    "");
}]);
```

I thought of writing a directive for close button to trigger the 'click" event of "POPOVER WITH CLOSE" button. But I am not sure if that's the approach to follow.

What's the correct approach to follow?

Comment: I still can't believe they haven't implemented a close button.

Answer (score 1):

The right solution now is to specify a popover template via the `uib-popover-template` attribute and bind your template's close button's `ng-click` handler to the popover's `popover-is-open` property.  We added this property to allow the user to "ignore" the provided trigger options (by specifying `popover-trigger="none"` and give the user full control over when to show and hide the popover.

You may see the updated docs (and examples) [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover).

Answer (score 0):

I changed the tooltip and popover code.

Here is how it looks like [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QhshtRqwpdsirvdFj9JG?p=preview)

Here is the [pull request](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/pull/654) for this.

Comment: Pity it isn't working though.. any plans to fix it? would be use useful! :)